# Manage object with given ID or specific field with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that contains two unique fields:

```py
class Instance(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

In `views.py`:

```py
class InstanceDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    queryset = Instance.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InstanceSerializer
```

In `urls.py`:

```
    path('<uuid:pk>/', InstanceDetail.as_view()),
```

Now, everything is working as expected and I can use the API with the instance ID's.

But what if I want to do the same using `name` instead of `id` ? So the API would work providing the `id` or the `name` to the same **url**? Is there an easy way to do this without duplicating any code ?

Comment: I would suggest to create two urls pointing to the same view, and fetching the kwargs argument accordingly if kwargs contains 'pk' filter on pk elif kwargs contains 'name' filter by name. you may need to override the get_object method I guess

Comment: @danish_wani I have just posted an answer with the exact same way you described, I didn't see your comment till the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents on this,

1. add `path('<str:name>/', InstanceDetail.as_view()),` to your `urls.py` along with the one you mentioned, so, you should have `two urls` using the same `view` now.
2. override `get_object()` to change `lookup_field` value based on which url is using the view.

So the final `views.py` will have :

```
class InstanceDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    queryset = Instance.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InstanceSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            self.lookup_field = 'pk'
        elif 'name' in self.kwargs:
            self.lookup_field = 'name'

        return super(InstanceDetail,self).get_object()
```

Comment: I found another solution similar to this one, with a single URL, but it looks way more clear this way.

Comment: To make you solution work, I had to change the last line of your code with ```return super(InstanceDetail,self).get_object()```

Comment: I missed out the return statement, sry about it, updated the answer

Comment: I would like to see the one with a single URL despite I'm guessing what happened there :D